# Connecting neo4j using neo4j-jdbc driver with Java

Tags: java, jdbc, neo4j

We a trying to connect neo4j using neo4j-jdbc driver with Java. 
The code we are trying to apply .

```
    try {
        Class.forName("org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver");
        // Conne

        System.out.println("GreetingServiceImpl.greetServer()");

        Connection connect =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:neo4j://localhost:7474/","neo4j","password");

        Statement stmt = connect.createStatement();
        String q = "MATCH (n:Question) RETURN n LIMIT 25";

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(q);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("n.QuesID"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println("bhalu");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

We are using the neo4j-jdbc jar version 2.3.1.
But now the problem is the dependencies of neo4j-jdbc jar.  We are unable to find the dependencies jar and its continuously giving error.

```
    Feb 11, 2016 12:17:06 PM org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver createDatabases
     WARNING: Embedded Neo4j support not enabled        
 org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService
    **com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.lang.String com.client.GreetingService.graphtheory() throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' threw an unexpected exception:** java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/cypherdsl/grammar/Execute
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:389)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:579)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:265)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:305)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:686)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at    org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:108 6)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:960)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1021)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/cypherdsl/grammar/Execute
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver.<init>(Driver.java:63)
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.Driver.<clinit>(Driver.java:46)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    at com.server.GreetingServiceImpl.graphtheory(GreetingServiceImpl.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
    ... 30 more
**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.cypherdsl.grammar.Execute**
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:531)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:407)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:383)
    ... 40 more
```

Even downloaded the  org/neo4j/cypherdsl/grammar/Execute jar but the grammar package is missing.
We want to code for neo4j in java without any maven dependencies. So, how can we find the depended jars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is you build config? Please try 2.3.2 of neo4j-jdbc

I don't understand why you don't want the dependencies,

but here you can see all jars that are generated by the build including your non-dependency-jar: https://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/org/neo4j/neo4j-jdbc/2.3.2/

Comment: Sir, I tried to search a lot but still couldn't find the neo4j-jdbc 2.3.2 jar without dependencies. We want the jar without dependencies as we are not using maven. I got the dependencies jar but didn't want it https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc.. If you could just help me and send me the link if you have or you get through anyway. It would be great for us

Comment: Thankyou Sir. Finally i have succede in running the code.

Comment: @Vartika can you help me with minimum code snippet for executing cypher using neo4j-jdbc. For me its always  `No suitable driver found for jdbc:neo4j://localhost:7474/ ` . I am using Groovy-Grails as API service to query Neo4j.